# Qt 4.8.4: Cannot connect slot to QListView::currentChanged() signal

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyside, qlistview

When connecting a slot to QListView::currentChanged(current, previous) signal using auto connection I get:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_modelosView_currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)
```

Not using auto connection I get:

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

I'm using PySide and my code is as follows:

```
class Modelos(QtGui.QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    # Inicializa o modelo
    self.model = ModelosModel(self)
    self.ui.modelosView.setModel(self.model)
    # Inicializa o mapper
    self.mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
    self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.ui.modelosEdit, 0)
    self.mapper.toFirst()
    self.ui.modelosView.currentChanged.connect(self.onmodelosView_currentChanged)

@QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QModelIndex, QtCore.QModelIndex)
def onmodelosView_currentChanged(self, current, previous):
    self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(current.row())
```

Where:
ModelosModel is a subclass of QtAbstractListModel and modelosView is a QListView widget.

My goal is to use this signal to update the mapper index so the user can select the item he wants in QListView and edit it in a QPlainTextEdit using a mapper.

Edit: To clear the confusion this is the code that originated the first error:

```
class Modelos(QtGui.QDialog):
def __init__(self, parent):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
    self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    # Inicializa o modelo
    self.model = ModelosModel(self)
    self.ui.modelosView.setModel(self.model)
    # Inicializa o mapper
    self.mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper(self)
    self.mapper.setModel(self.model)
    self.mapper.addMapping(self.ui.modelosEdit, 0)
    self.mapper.toFirst()

@QtCore.Slot(QtCore.QModelIndex, QtCore.QModelIndex)
def on_modelosView_currentChanged(self, current, previous):
    self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(current.row())
```

I was clearly using the auto connect feature but I got the error:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_modelosView_currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)
```

Comment: I don't know PySide _at all_, but haven't you decorated the `onmodelosView_currentChanged(..)` method as a slot, not a signal?

Comment: It is supposed to be a slot. Why do you think it should be a signal?

Comment: "No matching signal for on_modelosView_currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"

Comment: It should be matching modelosView::currentChanged(...) signal. modelosView is a QListView widget and should have a currentChanged signal to match my slot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was checking the docs for the tenth time and just realized that QListView::currentChanged(...) is actually a slot and not a signal. I just created a custom subclass of QListView with the signal I needed and made currentChanged emit that signal instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's not coming from your `connect()` statement, but from `setupUi()`.

By default, `setupUi()` adds a call to `QMetaObject::connectSignalsByName(widget)`, where `widget` is the argument passed to `setupUi()` (in your case: `self`).

That call, in turn, will look for all the slots of `self` with a name resembling

```
on_ChildObjectName_SignalName
```

and will try to figure out *if `self` has a child object named `ChildObjectName`* (in the sense of `QObject::objectName()`; if so, *it will try to connect its `SignalName`* to that slot. Obviously you don't anything like that.

Long story short: **don't name your slots using the `on_Child_Signal` pattern** unless you plan to use `connectSignalsByName`.

(On the other hand, it's quite convenient for widgets created using Designer: since Designer always give child widgets a name, you can easily hook up to their signals by using this feature, just create a slot called `on_Child_Signal` and it will magically work.)

Comment: The thing is, in the code above modelosView was created using the Designer and if you notice the error message in the first quote you will see the slot named on_modelosView_currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex).

So I do want to use the auto connect but it doesn't seem to be working on this  case and I have no idea why. I'm using auto connect in pretty much almost all my other slots.

What I did here was trying not to use the auto connect to see if it's working but it's not!

Comment: `(On the other hand, it's quite convenient for widgets created using Designer: since Designer always give child widgets a name, you can easily hook up to their signals by using this feature, just create a slot called on_Child_Signal and it will magically work.)` I did. and got `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_modelosView_currentChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)` error.

Comment: Strange. Is your view called exactly "modelosView" in the .ui?

Comment: Yes, it is. Check my second edit for the solution! Thanks for all the help!